# Shuffle function

Tags: python

I am using LED's and I'm trying to make them go in a random order. I have tried many searches but they all are showing music related stuff which totally changes the code. Please tell me what to edit in this code for that to happen.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO             ## Import GPIO Library
import time                         ## Import 'time' library (for 'sleep')

yellow = 17
green = 18
red = 22
blue = 4
## These are our LEDs
ourdelay = 0.1                      ## Delay
# pins 4,17,18,21,22,23,24,25

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)            ## Use BOARD pin numbering
GPIO.setup(yellow, GPIO.OUT)        ## set output
GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(blue, GPIO.OUT)
## function to save code

for num in range(1,30):
  print(num)
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.HIGH )
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.LOW)
  ## set HIGH (LED ON)
  time.sleep(ourdelay)                ## wait
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(ourdelay)                ## wait
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(ourdelay)        ## wait
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.HIGH)
  time.sleep(ourdelay)        ## wait

  ##activateLED(blue,ourdelay)

GPIO.cleanup()                      ## close down library
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. While it is not an issue wrt the question, something to consider for future coding: per [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) *Use 4 spaces per indentation level.*

Answer (score 1):

I haven't quite gone so far as to hook up the LEDs, but I think that's going to look something like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO             # Import GPIO Library
import time                         # Import 'time' library (for 'sleep')
import random                       # Import 'random' library 

# Delay
ourdelay = 0.1

# Use BOARD pin numbering
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Create a dictionary of pin names and numbers
my_led_dict = {'red': 22, 'yellow': 17, 'green': 18, 'blue': 4}

# Set up every pin in our dictionary as an output
for led_pin_number in my_led_dict.values():
    GPIO.setup(led_pin_number, GPIO.OUT)

# Set up the random function with a seed value
random.seed()

for num in range(1,30):
    print(num)

    # Choose a random pin from our dictionary
    chosen_led = random.choice(my_led_dict.values())
    print("Selected pin is " + str(chosen_led))

    # Iterate over each value in our dictionary
    for led_pin_number in my_led_dict.values():
        if led_pin_number == chosen_led:
            GPIO.output(led_pin_number, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("Set pin number " + str(led_pin_number) + " to GPIO.HIGH")
        else:
            GPIO.output(led_pin_number, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Set pin number " + str(led_pin_number) + " to GPIO.LOW")        

    # Wait
    time.sleep(ourdelay)

# Close down library
GPIO.cleanup()
```